# log in to a webpage and capture screenshot in vb6

Tags: http, vb6, screenshot

I have a visual basic 6 application that needs to get pictures from a particular website but the problem is that the users have to open the webpage on the browser and log in to the webpage then download the picture and upload it in the vb6 app. Is it possible to have the vb6 go to that webpage and log in and capture the screenshot and save it in a particular folder without opening the browser?
The url opens the login page by default and you have to log in first, to access the picture page, which we just have to take a screen shot and crop it.

Is this possible in pure VB6?

Comment: It depends a lot on the website. At its simplest, you can just request the image's URL directly if you can determine what it is. You can try looking at the web browser control and using its automation methods to control the page and login.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some VERY generic code that will log you into a website. It is basically a matter of finding the controls in the browser document and filling in the correct values. Since you have provided no code to build on it's up to you to fill in all the correct values. This is using **Microsoft Internet Controls** to add a browser control to a form.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim i As Integer

    WebBrowser1.Navigate ("http://URL of the page you want to go to")
    Do While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
    If InStr(WebBrowser1.LocationURL, "http://targetwebsite/login.aspx") Then
        On Error Resume Next
        For i = 0 To WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).length - 1
            ' Uncommenting the MsgBox method will display the control names and help find the controls you are looking for
            'MsgBox WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0)(i).Type & ", " & WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0)(i).Name
            If WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0)(i).Type = "text" Then
                WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0)(i).Value = "user name"
            End If
            If WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0)(i).Type = "password" Then
                WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0)(i).Value = "user password"
            End If
        Next i
        ' now find and click the submit button
        For i = 0 To WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).length - 1
            If WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0)(i).Type = "submit" Then
                WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0)(i).Click
            End If
        Next i
    End If

    ' You should now be logged in and loading the page you want
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks alot your code helped me successfully log in to the webpage,could you help me capture the screenshot and save it as an image and maybe crop it if possible?